# no matching function for call to 'dot' and 'reflect'

Tags: ios, swift, shader, arkit, metal

I am trying to run ARBrush iOS ARKit app available in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/laanlabs/ARBrush/tree/master/ARBrush). which is a really cool 3D drawing app! Unfortunately, I am getting 2 errors. I don't know why I am getting these errors and how to solve them. 
the first error is " no matching function for call to 'dot' " for line 104 in shaders.metal:

```
 float diffuseFactor = max(0.0,dot(interpolated.normal, light.direction)); // 1
```

The second one is " no matching function for call to 'reflect' " in line 109 in the same file (shaders.metal)

```
float3 reflection = reflect(light.direction, interpolated.normal); // 2
```

Below is my complete error report

```
CompileMetalFile /Users/Myname/Documents/Xcode/ARBrush/ARBrush/Shaders.metal (in target: ARBrush)
    cd /Users/Myname/Documents/Xcode/ARBrush
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/metal -arch air64 -emit-llvm -c -gline-tables-only -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -ffast-math -serialize-diagnostics /Users/Myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARBrush-amgfmkvulxeadccjphanytgyilwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARBrush.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARBrush.build/Metal/Shaders.dia -o /Users/Myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARBrush-amgfmkvulxeadccjphanytgyilwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARBrush.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARBrush.build/Metal/Shaders.air -mios-version-min=11.0 "" -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARBrush-amgfmkvulxeadccjphanytgyilwe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ARBrush.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARBrush.build/Metal/Shaders.dat /Users/Myname/Documents/Xcode/ARBrush/ARBrush/Shaders.metal

/Users/Myname/Documents/Xcode/ARBrush/ARBrush/Shaders.metal:104:35: error: no matching function for call to 'dot'
    float diffuseFactor = max(0.0,dot(interpolated.normal, light.direction)); // 1
                                  ^~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/lib/clang/902.1/include/metal/metal_geometric:171:30: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_geometric_binary_func_enable<float __attribute__((ext_vector_type(3))), float __attribute__((packed_vector_type(3)))>::value' was not satisfied [with T = float __attribute__((ext_vector_type(3))), U = float __attribute__((packed_vector_type(3)))]
METAL_FUNC make_scalar_t<_O> dot(T x, U y)
                             ^
/Users/Myname/Documents/Xcode/ARBrush/ARBrush/Shaders.metal:109:25: error: no matching function for call to 'reflect'
    float3 reflection = reflect(light.direction, interpolated.normal); // 2
                        ^~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/lib/clang/902.1/include/metal/metal_geometric:354:15: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '_geometric_binary_func_enable<float __attribute__((packed_vector_type(3))), float __attribute__((ext_vector_type(3)))>::value' was not satisfied [with T = float __attribute__((packed_vector_type(3))), U = float __attribute__((ext_vector_type(3)))]
METAL_FUNC _O reflect(T i, U n)
              ^
2 errors generated.
```

I am running this app using swift 4 on Xcode 10.1 and my development target is iOS 11. I will be so thankful if anyone can address my problems.

Thank you

Comment: Please show the entire shader compiler output, verbatim. You may need to copy it from the build log.

Comment: @KenThomases I updated my Question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue occurs because the functions in the Metal standard library don't accept *packed* vector types. You should be able to fix this with an inline type conversion at the call site:

```
float diffuseFactor = max(0.0,dot(interpolated.normal, float3(light.direction))); // 1

float3 reflection = reflect(float3(light.direction), interpolated.normal); // 2
```

or simply create a local variable of non-packed type

```
float3 lightDir(light.direction);
```

and use that in each call instead of passing the struct member directly.